Cant install kdeplasma-addons using apt
I use Ubuntu Mate 22.04 on my computer and I installed the KDE Plasma desktop environment, I tried adding the Menu 11 and Menu X Widgets but they popped up with an error when I tried to open them I searched how to fix it and was told to run:
sudo apt install kdeplasma-addons

but this fails, the output is:
E: Unable to locate package kdeplasma-addons

how do I fix this i have already tried to run sudo apt update
even weirder is when I switch to the Wayland version the problem is fixed
also for some reason I can't ask this because ask ubuntu thinks universal is the same as kdeplasma-addons
